# using JS to parse an AWS file represented in a download URL

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, url, download

I am using React and JS to build a web app that relies on the REST API of a private web service. Using the API, I can obtain a url for a CSV file that contains data from a server process. The url can be used to download the CSV results from AWS to the user's desktop. The URL is of the form...

```
https://[identifier1].s3.amazonaws.com/[path and filename.csv]
?X-Amz-Algorithm=[identifier2]
&X-Amz-Date=20210602T001523Z
&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
&X-Amz-Expires=3599
&X-Amz-Credential=[identifier3]
%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request
&X-Amz-Signature=[identifier4]
```

(I inserted line feeds above for readability)

My problem is, I don't want the file saved to my local device, I want to parse it directly and read it into a js structure. For example, I would like to display the data directly in a table.

I could download the file and then have the user upload the saved file into the app, but that is not a great workflow. Is there a straightforward way to use the data directly without saving it as a local file?

Comment: Browser js has the XMLHttpRequest class to make requests, or there are a lot of libraries that streamline the process.

Comment: ...or the more modern `fetch` function (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).